# Upgrading eclipse while keeping plugins

Tags: eclipse

Is there an easy way to upgrade eclipse while keeping all custom installed plugins (e.g. m2eclipse, spring ide, hibernate, etc.)? Everytime I upgraded eclipse, I had to re-install all of my plugins. It gets tiresome and reduces my desire to upgrade.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes , you may refer [this](http://lenettoyeur-on-eclipse.blogspot.com/2011/06/from-helios-to-indigo-is-easy.html) to see if it works for just upgrading the eclipse via the  `Help--> Check for update`.

It works if the new version of eclipse is compatible with the plug-ins you are using

Comment: I never had much success with this function. Perhaps with the latest from